# Can I edit the contents of my static website after publishing?

Tags: hosting, web-hosting

I want to publish a website through google domains.
The problem is that I am shifting my office to a new location so, I want to change the map on my website after one month.
Are there any possibilities to edit the website after publishing?

Comment: As your site is static. So, you can make any changes as you want. it will not impact your website because its static. You can even change your map on your website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a static website, sure you can update the information you like. Most web hosting services usually use GitHub as a platform for developers to host it. Meaning, you just need to make the necessary changes to your file, upload to Github. Then the hosting services will detect the change and update your site accordingly